# Calculate projected area in Cinema 4D

Tags: software, 3d

I would like to calculate the projected area of an object in Cinema 4D R12 on the Mac. Initially I am fine with calculating the projected area on one of the principal planes, but if a method exists where I can choose my object and a plane on which the projected area should be calculated this would be exquisite.

I am willing to learn python, COFFEE and/or Xpresso to accomplish this.

Comment: Nobody? I'm now exporting the polygon as an Allplan xml file, reading that in with Matlab, taking the xy,yz or zx coordinates only and plotting a polygon with them. But that seems a bit cumbersome. Could I do this with Python?